# IoT Central: Reuse module across device templates

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-central

In Azure IoT Central, we can create device templates comprised of modules. I have a requirement to use modules across different device templates.
For example:
A thermostat module can be reused across AHU or FCU device templates.

Has someone tried reusing modules across device templates in IoT Central?

Comment: have a look at an example of **dtmi:com:example:TemperatureController;2** https://github.com/Azure/iot-plugandplay-models/blob/main/dtmi/com/example/temperaturecontroller-2.json Note, that the REST API to query devices is driven by a device template instance, in other words, you have to use a multiple queries  to follow up the device model (modules, components, etc.), see doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-query-with-rest-api

Comment: Thanks Roman, I have been through it but doesn't seem helpful to reuse a module across device templates.